# React component doesn't show up on Heroku but shows on local

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am trying to deploy my react app on heroku but only shows index.html without all the components. The app is working fine on localhost. I made a form.js for creating server for nodemailer.

my directory looks like

```
src
 - index.js
form.js
package.json
```

my package.json

```
{
 "name": "earthly",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
 "engines": {
 "node": "8.11.1",
 "npm": "6.2.0"
},
 "dependencies": {
 "axios": "^0.18.0",
 "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
 "concurrently": "^3.6.0",
 "data.js": "^0.11.5",
 "express": "^4.16.3",
 "nodemailer": "^4.6.7",
 "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
 "npm": "^6.2.0",
 "react": "^16.4.1",
 "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
 "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
 "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
 "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
 "react-stripe-elements": "^2.0.1",
 "reactstrap": "^6.3.0"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "concurrently \"cross-env NODE_PATH=src react- 
scripts start\" \"node index.js\"",
"server": "nodemon form.js",
"dev": "npm run server",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src react-scripts test -- 
env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"devDependencies": {
"cross-env": "^5.2.0"
},
```

form.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0', function(err) {
console.log("Started listening on %s", app.url);
});
```

Build log on Heroku

```
Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  8.11.1
   engines.npm (package.json):   6.2.0

   Resolving node version 8.11.1...
   Downloading and installing node 8.11.1...
   Bootstrapping npm 6.2.0 (replacing 5.6.0)...
   npm 6.2.0 installed
-----> Restoring cache
   Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
   - node_modules
   - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
   Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
   audited 21180 packages in 16.791s
   found 20 moderate severity vulnerabilities
   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for 
details
-----> Caching build
   Clearing previous node cache
   Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
   - node_modules
   - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Pruning devDependencies
   removed 3 packages and audited 21170 packages in 
14.867s
   found 20 moderate severity vulnerabilities
   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for 
details
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> react, web
-----> Compressing...
   Done: 62.6M
-----> Launching...
   Released v45
   https://earthly.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

I am a student and it is my first time making app with react and heroku so don't know about what to do. If someone can help it would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean without your "components?" Is it not loading index.js in index.html? Also, could you show your procfile and index.html files?

Comment: No it wasn't loading index.js. But I fixed it. I had to remove my devDependencies and add "heroku-postbuild": "NODE_PATH=src react-scripts build"on script. Also on form.js I added 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0', function(err) {
  console.log("Started listening on %s", app.url);
});
Thank you Kyle anyways!